# Why only my last local notification function is getting called?

Tags: swift, notifications, usernotifications

I'm fairly new to swift and am trying to call multiple functions that request a local notification inside a UISwitch IBAction. I want to send a notification on a certain date - each quarter of the year on months 4, 7, 10, 1. Only the fourth quarter function is getting called. How can I get all four functions to be called? Here is my code:

// UISwitch for quarterly notifications

```
@IBAction func quarterlyFrequencyTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {

if quarterlyFrequency.isOn == true {

    firstQuarter(); secondQuarter(); thirdQuarter(); fourthQuarter()

    print("quarterly frequency is \(quarterlyFrequency.isOn)")

} else {

    removeQuarterlyNotification()

    print("quaterly frequency is \(monthlyFrequency.isOn)")

       }

}
```

// Functions for all four quarters

```
func firstQuarter() {
    let firstQuarterContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    firstQuarterContent.title = "First Quarter"
    firstQuarterContent.subtitle = "Some string"
    firstQuarterContent.body = "Some other string"

    var firstQuarterDate = DateComponents()
    firstQuarterDate.month = 3
    firstQuarterDate.day = 11
    firstQuarterDate.hour = 19
    firstQuarterDate.minute = 20

    let firstQuarterTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: firstQuarterDate, repeats: true)
    let firstQuarterRequestIdentifier = "Quarterly"
    let firstQuarterRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: firstQuarterRequestIdentifier, content: firstQuarterContent, trigger: firstQuarterTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(firstQuarterRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

func secondQuarter() {
    let secondQuarterContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    secondQuarterContent.title = "Second Quarter"
    secondQuarterContent.subtitle = "Some string"
    secondQuarterContent.body = "Some other string"

    var secondQuarterDate = DateComponents()
    secondQuarterDate.month = 3
    secondQuarterDate.day = 11
    secondQuarterDate.hour = 19
    secondQuarterDate.minute = 21

    let secondQuarterTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: secondQuarterDate, repeats: true)
    let secondQuarterRequestIdentifier = "Quarterly"
    let secondQuarterRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: secondQuarterRequestIdentifier, content: secondQuarterContent, trigger: secondQuarterTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(secondQuarterRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

func thirdQuarter() {
    let thirdQuarterContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    thirdQuarterContent.title = "Third Quarter"
    thirdQuarterContent.subtitle = "Some string"
    thirdQuarterContent.body = "Some other string"

    var thirdQuarterDate = DateComponents()
    thirdQuarterDate.month = 3
    thirdQuarterDate.day = 11
    thirdQuarterDate.hour = 19
    thirdQuarterDate.minute = 22

    let thirdQuarterTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: thirdQuarterDate, repeats: true)
    let thirdQuarterRequestIdentifier = "Quarterly"
    let thirdQuarterRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: thirdQuarterRequestIdentifier, content: thirdQuarterContent, trigger: thirdQuarterTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(thirdQuarterRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

func fourthQuarter() {
    let fourthQuarterContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    fourthQuarterContent.title = "Fourth Quarter"
    fourthQuarterContent.subtitle = "Some string"
    fourthQuarterContent.body = "Some other string"

    var fourthQuarterDate = DateComponents()
    fourthQuarterDate.month = 3
    fourthQuarterDate.day = 11
    fourthQuarterDate.hour = 19
    fourthQuarterDate.minute = 23

    let fourthQuarterTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: fourthQuarterDate, repeats: true)
    //let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
    let fourthQuarterRequestIdentifier = "Quarterly"
    let fourthQuarterRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: fourthQuarterRequestIdentifier, content: fourthQuarterContent, trigger: fourthQuarterTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(fourthQuarterRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: How do you know only the fourth is being called?  There's nothing wrong with this block of code.

Comment: this `firstQuarter(); secondQuarter(); thirdQuarter(); fourthQuarter()` executes all 4...nothing wrong with.

Perhaps your functions work incorrectly themselves

Comment: To test this, I'm setting up each quarter's function one minute apart and run the simulator. Only the fourth notification runs in the simulator.

Comment: No. All 4 functions are being called with that line of code.  You have something else wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're on +iOS10 and you're using UserNotifications framework right?

Very likely your `identifier`s have the **same** and each are **UPDATING** the previous notification.

The reason `identifier` exists is to assist you with updated a previous notification that has the same identifier. For example you send a notification to update the score from `0-0` to `0-1`. And instead of having 2 notifications on the screen you now have only one.

Your fix is to use *different* identifiers for each.

For more see this [moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/?time=1120) for the WWDC video

**UPDATE after your edit:**
just as I said...all your notifications have `"Quarterly"` as their identifier. Give them each a separate name.

Comment: @nsd32 since you're new here. Once you get an answer you like, it's recommended to 1. upvote it 2. click on the check to [mark it as accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I just clicked on the checkmark, however since my reputation is still low, the upvote does not show but apparently it still gets recorded somewhere. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little help

You can just add UUID().uuidString for identifier.

Kudos Honey