# Why notification in ios shows only first attachment from the attachment array even if there is one more.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I am scheduling a local notification with the attachment array having two files. First one is image and second one is a audio file. When notification is delivered it shows only the first attachement, whether it is audio or image. Is it possible to show multiple attachments without subclassing the UNNotificationContentExtension class and creating the custom interface. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: u r attaching data or filepath?

Comment: i am attaching url (NSURL) of the file .

Comment: You haven't showed your code, but very likely it's because you're using identical `identifier`s. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742926/why-only-my-last-local-notification-function-is-getting-called/42743041#42743041)

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that multiple attachments can only be handled by your own custom `Notification Content` extensions, as of iOS 11.

The standard iOS notification content view only displays the first attachment. It even discards any additional attachments from the `UNNotification`. When you look at a notification that was created with multiple attachments and is displayed by retrieving it with `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications` you will find that it contains only 1 attachment and all others have been discarded.