# Local Notification in IOS 11 and swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios11, swift4

My app works perfectly  on ios 10 but on ios 11 it does not push local Notification.
Is there any error in my code?

```
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
let sound = self.defaults.string(forKey: "azan")!
// Configure Notification Content
notificationContent.title = "کاتەکانی بانگ"
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: sound)
//notificationContent.subtitle =  self.notificationstring
notificationContent.body = self.notificationstring

// Add Trigger

if(TimeInterval(time) > 0)
{
    let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(time), repeats: false)

    // Create Notification Request
    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    // Add Request to User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Could you post what error you're getting?

Comment: @crashlog he said there is no error!

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try giving this a unique identifier? For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742926/why-only-my-last-local-notification-function-is-getting-called/42743041#42743041)

Comment: its worked for me , in ios 11 app can saving only 60 notification on the queue , if more than ignore all notifications